# G Suite channel stop function with the Admin SDK not working

Tags: google-workspace

Here is the scenario and setup

1. I'm using [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/channels/stop) to watch changes in the users data ([Python API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.channels.html))
2. The notification is being sent to a Google Cloud Function
3. The setup is working correctly.
4. The issue is when I'm trying to stop watching the resource by using the SDK it says 
   `<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop? returned "Not Found">`

I'm sure I'm using the right *id* and *resourceId*. Does anyone know why it is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

The API states the Endpoint URL is `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop` but the URL in the call is `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop`

The issue is with the SDK itself, the `stop` API is the only one in the documentation with `_v1` and not `/v1`. I believe this is the reason for the issue with the API. Just make a regular HTTP Post notification instead

Comment: And here is the reported issue https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/403